How would I take input and output data on multiple tmux terminal using a cpp program?
The code below creates two panes in tmux and counts down to 20.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

// Function to execute a shell command and get the result
std::string exec(const std::string& cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

// Function to be executed by each thread
void threadFunction(const std::string& tty, std::atomic<bool>& running, int threadId) {
    int messageCount = 0;
    std::ofstream ttyStream(tty);
    if (!ttyStream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open tty: " << tty << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    while (running.load()) {
        ttyStream << "Thread " << threadId << " is running: message " << messageCount++ << std::endl;
        ttyStream.flush();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

void kill(const std::string& sessionName){
    std::string command = "tmux send-keys -t " + sessionName + " \" tmux kill-server\" Enter";

    // Capture output for debugging
    std::string output = exec(command); // Assuming `exec` returns the output
    std::cerr << "Command output: " << output << std::endl;

    if (std::system(command.c_str()) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error executing command: " << command << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    const std::string sessionName = "Client";
    const int numThreads = 2; // Number of threads and panes

    // Create tmux session and panes, and get their TTYs
    std::string createSessionCmd = "tmux new-session -d -s " + sessionName + " -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null'";
    std::string pane1 = exec(createSessionCmd);
    pane1.pop_back(); // Remove newline character

    std::string splitPaneCmd = "tmux split-window -t " + sessionName + " -PF '#{pane_id}' 'tail -f /dev/null'";
    std::string pane2 = exec(splitPaneCmd);
    pane2.pop_back(); // Remove newline character

    std::string getTtyCmd1 = "tmux display-message -p -t " + pane1 + " '#{pane_tty}'";
    std::string tty1 = exec(getTtyCmd1);
    tty1.pop_back(); // Remove newline character

    std::string getTtyCmd2 = "tmux display-message -p -t " + pane2 + " '#{pane_tty}'";
    std::string tty2 = exec(getTtyCmd2);
    tty2.pop_back(); // Remove newline character

    std::cout << "TTY1: " << tty1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TTY2: " << tty2 << std::endl;

    std::atomic<bool> running(true);

    // Create and run threads
    std::thread t1(threadFunction, tty1, std::ref(running), 1);
    std::thread t2(threadFunction, tty2, std::ref(running), 2);
    
    std::thread t3([&sessionName]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20)); // Increase sleep time for testing
    
        std::string command = "tmux new-window -t " + sessionName + " -n thread" + std::to_string(2);
        std::system(command.c_str());
        kill(sessionName);

    });

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    t3.detach();

    

    // Attach to the tmux session
    std::string cmd = "tmux attach -t " + sessionName;
    std::system(cmd.c_str());

    return 0;
}

The problem I am facing is that the panes are not able to take any input. I want thread to display messages on the assigned pane. But if a user wants to send message the pane can take any input then this input should be displayed in the other pane. Meaning the counting messages stop when it is taking input and then display the message and start counting from where it left off. But in the above code it can't do that but not just that but I can't run any command. So even to close the tmux session I have to create a new tmux window and use kill-server on the new tmux window.
If I don't use tty then I have to make it so that in each pane whenever an user enters a string of characters to not consider it as a command and write those into a file and then will need to have a new thread to read from this file and display that in particular pane.
But when I don't use tty then each "input + Enter" gives the output that input was not a command and as you can see on the top pane to display anything the cpp file needs to run "echo 'message' + Enter". Meaning the message displays twice


"the panes are not able to take any input" -- input from where?  "I want thread to display messages on the assigned pane" -- i tried your program and there are indeed messages sent to both panes so what's the problem here? "But if a user wants to send message the pane can take any input then this input should be displayed in the other pane." -- what do you mean? overall it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. could you elaborate?

@pynexj Sorry for being unclear what I mean is the threads are displaying messages but not able to take any input during that time like when we use getline(cin, str). When the pane is displaying message if the user tries to put any input then the thread should stop displaying and take the input in a string and then when the user presses enter the other pane stops and the input string is displayed and then both panes again start counting from where they stopped. Just before the sleep(1000) it should check if user tried to input anything if not continue counting otherwise take input

@pynexj Before this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000)); check for any input character if input then take input into string and display in other pane but if no character input then just keep counting

which part of your code is trying to "take any input"?

@pynexj Before the sleep(1000) I want it to check if user has input any character using a function like getline(cin,str) in the code it is not shown because it was not working to take any input. Even if it is in the code it doesn't work.

when you tmux attach, tmux would get the control of the terminal and user input would be consumed by tmux.

Tmux is a client server architecture. Whenever you create a new session/windows/pane, the server allocates a new external virtual/terminal to that element just like is has been manually started from elsewhere.
This means that each tmux has its own stdin/stdout that notwithstandign you started each session with a popen call have nothing to do with the endpoints of the pipe. Those endpoint are uniquely related to the "tmux client" whose command is consumed immediately.
Nonetheless, you may: 1) send key-sequences to the windows/panes you created through the send-key comamand; 2) collect and receive output from "manually started" (with send-keys) panes-processes using sort of handmade IPC (named pipes, tcpip,...).
Remember that being children-process of different virtual-terminals, each pane/windows will run a different process whose code can be a clone of your program or a second external program. There is no way to have a multhtreaded program handling many tmux-items unless you do not write a dumb I/O hub-tranceiver process for each of them. Otherwise if you want to use a single multi-threaded process and simply need to split the screen in parts, curses library has windows that may serve your scope.
